# Anybody Use Multiple Editions of Assimil in Parallel?

Tags: educación

I find myself in possession of two editions of Assimil's Spanish course with a third edition on it's way. Namely I have the 1957 edition of Spanish Without Toil, and the 1987 edition (actually recent printing) of Spanish with Ease. I also have ordered, but have not received, the new English base version of L'Espagnol directly from Assimil. The 1957 and 1987 editions are definitely different and I believe the as yet unreceived L'Espagnol is also a new different text. All three have an English base. I am tempted to do one lesson from each edition every day.

Has anybody tried to work with multiple editions of Assimil in parallel? If yes, was it helpful? I suspect that eventually my enthusiasm may wane a bit but I think I can keep this up for 5 months or so.

Would this be helpful? Am I confusing myself? Will I hate the name Assimil by the time I am done?

Comment: This question is currently asking for opinions, which doesn't work very well on this site. We're much better at answering objective questions. Perhaps you can rephrase this question to be more objective, perhpas by asking for the differences between versions?

Comment: Even so, this sort of question really isn't our speciality... we focus more on the Spanish langauge itself, rather than learning resources. There is a chance this sort of question _might_ be better recieved at [Linguistics.SE](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/), but I'm not sure, so be sure to read their FAQ before posting there, too.